# Filter NOT equals in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter

I have a array of objects, in client side.
The object in array look like this:

```
{
    code: 0,
    short_name: 'a',
    type: 1
}
```

I try to filter this array to 2 arrays:

1. With type === 1
2. With type !== 1

I did this:

```
$scope.array1 = $filter('filter')(data, {type: 1}, true);
$scope.array1 = $filter('filter')(data, {type: !1});
```

But the not-equal didn't work... what can I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Again, if you are just going to `filter`, use the [native method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead:

```
$scope.array1 = data.filter(x => x.type === 1);
$scope.array2 = data.filter(x => x.type !== 1);
```

Comment: I can't try this, because I can't use in ES6.

Comment: @prog_prog your welcome, glad to help! (I am sorry for the es2015 syntax is just that I love it so much :P)

Comment: I like it too... maybe in the future... :-)

Comment: @Kutyel , check this fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/33383/` , why last one is not display in list, event last one id is -12 not -1 ??

Comment: Hi @chiragsatapara, check the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/33384/, its a more practical example of how to use JS native functions instead of the angular "magic", which seems to be doing a string comparison or something like that (if this helped you please upvote the answer ;)

Comment: @Kutyel, for apply angular 'magic' , i have to make so much changes in my code , is there no way apply it in div using `|| filter : filters : true` instead of js??

Comment: @Kutyel , if i change filter from ng-repeat , i have to make so much changes in my code , and it is not good for me.

Answer (score 3):

You're very close. You just need to change your second filter to:

```
$scope.array2 = $filter('filter')(data, { type: '!1' });
```

I also renamed the scope variable since otherwise it would just overwrite your first filtered array.

Comment: I tried it before but it's didn't work well... because this filter remove also all the object with type that include 1 (like: 12, 13, etc.)

Comment: But suppose you are using a key instead of string then just edit above like..          
                     '!' + your_key

Answer (score 1):

For me the given solution `{ type: '!1' }` doesn't work when used with `true` as last parameter `$filter('filter')(data, {type: 1}, true);`. However using a function works for me (see [angular's doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)):

```
$scope.array2 = $filter('filter')(data, function(value, index, array) {
            return (value.type !== 1);
        }, true);
```